# What to call a winged unicorn?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

What is a word for a winged unicorn or horned pegasus? I've heard a few ways of describing such a fantastical beast, but I don't know which is correct.

[image]

They are known as both Alicorns (*[ali-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alicorn)* supposedly from *ala* (wing), and *corn* meaning horn), as well as Pegi(a)corn, a portmanteau of Pegasus and Unicorn (I've seen both an *i* and an *a* used).

which of these is most 'correct', and did one come first? Furthermore, Wikipedia says that

> ### Alicorn
>
> The horn itself [of the unicorn] and the substance it was made of was called alicorn, and it was believed that the horn holds magical and medicinal properties

So that would make my supposed etymology above wrong.

Comment: I think Pegasus has wings but no horn. I googled Alicorn and that looks like the closest match.

Comment: @Roy I googled it too but I came up with the fact that originally Alicorn was the substance that made up the horn.

Comment: @mgb This is an issue from various fiction writers, as well as fans of a certain TV show featuring ponies. I wouldn't say those two groups make this question too localized.

Comment: I've migrated the question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15572/what-to-call-a-winged-unicorn

Comment: Now that too localised is no longer a valid close reason,  could this get reopened.

Comment: @Pureferret - No. It would just get closed for another reason instead. I've seen many questions closed for asking for made-up words; I suspect this would get the same treatment.

Comment: @AndyT aren't all words are made up, to some extent?

Answer (score 5):

Alicorn is the most common word used to describe said beast, however, in the [Xanth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth) series, there are also PegaCorns and UniPegs.  All three creatures look exactly the same in the series, which is a subtle joke, and the only way to tell them apart is to ask them.